# Как отключить из бэкэнда апстрим в nginx

Tags: python, nginx

Есть web-приложение на python, через supervisor запускается 4 копии. В качестве фронтэнда - nginx с настройками балансировки по умолчанию (round robin). В пике частота запросов достигает 1 запроса в секунду. Не много.
Но есть один url, который работает около 5 минут. Первый человек его запросил и спокойно ждёт. И бывает часто такое, что другие пользователи попадает как раз на этот же инстанс, с этим долгим запросом и ждут. Хотя другие инстансы обрабатывают быстрые url и этих пользователей можно было бы проксировать туда.
Есть ли какой заголовок, или ещё какой метод, позволяющий на время обработки этого запроса выключить из очереди данный инстанс, а после обработки включить обратно?

Comment: А что будет когда этот урл запросят 4 человека и займут все 4 копии?

Comment: Переписать приложение так, что бы оно само себе было супервизором, т.е. занимало один единственный порт, после этого размножалось в нужном количестве. Тогда любая из копий будет забирать сама коннект из очереди с помощью accept.

Comment: @Mike, хороший вариант, тоже думал об этом.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, трём последующим будет сказано, что задача уже запущена другим пользователем. Это админская часть и к ней имеют доступ только 2 человека.

Comment: Ну можно же просто запустить ещё одну копию и настроить nginx что бы этот конкретный урл ходил в эту специальную копию, а остальные урлы ходили в остальные 4 копии

Comment: @AlexeyTen, этот вариант тоже рассматривался.